# How do I center text relative to its parent div with CSS?

Tags: html, css

I know I can use `text-align: center;` on the parent div to center all its child elements, but what if I don't want all the child elements centered? I just want, say, one child element centered relative to the parent.

Say I have everything within a wrapper div. Some headers, forms, etc. But at the bottom I want to center a small line of text crediting something. How would I achieve that if its hierarchy is body > div.wrapper > div.credit?

Comment: What's wrong with `.credit {text-align: center;}`?

Comment: The markup would help a lot here.  How you center a div is very different from how you center the inline contents of a div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So why you are complicating the CSS here? Simply wrap that text in a div and use `text-align: center;` for that particular div and you are done

And if you want to declare in a CSS hierarchy manner just use this

```
body div:last-child {
   text-align: center;
}
```

> Note: Be sure the text you want to be centered is the last div you are
>   using else don't use last-child selector, better declare a class

Answer (score 0):

Only specify which div to centre by saying which one:

```
div {
text-align:/* whatever align for the rest */
}

div:credit {
text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: Don't be rude, you are using colon instead of a period